# How can I delete content of all directory files in Linux?

Tags: linux

I would like to know how to delete the content of each file that a directory contains in Linux.

Comment: [How to remove all files from a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60228/how-to-remove-all-files-from-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Say we are concerned with the directory /home/foo, you can use find with exec and so:

```
find /home/foo -type file -exec bash -c "echo \"\" > '{}'" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES_LOC_AND_TYPE=./*.log
for filename in $FILES_LOC_AND_TYPE; do
        echo "" > $filename
done
```

FILES_LOC_AND_TYPE specifies where the dir is located and it is possible to define the files pattern to empty (in this example all the log files).